# Pyspark how to compare two data frame without a unique/primary identifier

Tags: sql, pandas, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, data-comparison

I am trying to compare two data set derived from hive and snowflake. These data set doesn't have unique identifier or primary key defined. so the challenge here is to verify the transaction of company from hive against respective snowflake rows.

```
hive_df
+---+-----+-----+----+------+------+
|trans_id| comp_name  |dept |  date|
+--------+-----+------+-----+------+
|1101    | Johnaon&jho| acnt|2-3-21|
|1101    | Johnaon&jho| acnt|2-3-21|
|1102    | jeo_cop    | sales|3-2-21
|1103    | star       | acnt| 4-2-21
+---+-----+-----+------+-----------+
```

```
snowflake_df
+---+-----+-----+----+------+------+
|trans_id| comp_name  |dept |  date|
+--------+-----+------+-----+------+
|1101    | Johnaon&jho| acnt|2-3-21|
|1101    | Johnaon&jho| acnt|2-3-21|
|1102    | jeo_cop    | sales|3-2-21
|1103    | star       | acnt| 4-2-21|
+---+-----+-----+------+-----------+
```

i see many example to join two data frame using unique id and compare the difference using pyspark such as

```
joined_df=source_df\
    .join(dest_df, 'key', 'full')
report = joined_df\
                    .filter((source_df[column] != dest_df[column]))
```

but what is the solution when data set does not have unique identifier? and how to compare actually? Any solution please

Comment: Presumably, `Anti` join exactly what you need. See this https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-join.html#anti-join

Answer (score 1):

I have used the following approach for many years.
**union all** with combination of **group by** and conditional count gives you a full picture of the data and handles duplications gracefully.

**Generation of the sample dataframes**

```
cols = ["trans_id","comp_name","dept","date"]

hive_data = \
[("1101","Johnaon&jho","acnt","2-3-21")
,("1101","Johnaon&jho","acnt","2-3-21")
,("1102","jeo_cop","sales","3-2-21")]

snowflake_data = \
[("1101","Johnaon&jho","acnt","2-3-21")
,("1101","Johnaon&jho","acnt","2-3-21")
,("1102","jeo_cop","sales","3-2-21")]

hive_df = spark.createDataFrame(hive_data, cols)
snowflake_df = spark.createDataFrame(snowflake_data, cols)
```

---

```
hive_df.show()

+--------+-----------+-----+------+
|trans_id|  comp_name| dept|  date|
+--------+-----------+-----+------+
|    1101|Johnaon&jho| acnt|2-3-21|
|    1101|Johnaon&jho| acnt|2-3-21|
|    1102|    jeo_cop|sales|3-2-21|
+--------+-----------+-----+------+
```

---

```
snowflake_df.show()

+--------+-----------+-----+------+
|trans_id|  comp_name| dept|  date|
+--------+-----------+-----+------+
|    1101|Johnaon&jho| acnt|2-3-21|
|    1101|Johnaon&jho| acnt|2-3-21|
|    1102|    jeo_cop|sales|3-2-21|
+--------+-----------+-----+------+
```

**Solution, based on df_unionall & groupBy**

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

hive_df_1 = hive_df.withColumn('source_system',F.lit('hive'))
snowflake_df_1 = snowflake_df.withColumn('source_system',F.lit('snow_flake'))

df_unionall = (hive_df_1
               .unionAll(snowflake_df_1)
               .groupBy(hive_df.columns)
               .agg(
                 F.count("*").alias('total'),
                 F.count(F.when(F.col('source_system') == "hive",1)).alias('hive'),
                 F.count(F.when(F.col('source_system') == "snow_flake",1)).alias('snowflake')
               )
              )

df_unionall.show()
```

---

```
+--------+-----------+-----+------+-----+----+---------+
|trans_id|  comp_name| dept|  date|total|hive|snowflake|
+--------+-----------+-----+------+-----+----+---------+
|    1101|Johnaon&jho| acnt|2-3-21|    4|   2|        2|
|    1102|    jeo_cop|sales|3-2-21|    2|   1|        1|
+--------+-----------+-----+------+-----+----+---------+
```

Comment: HI @David, i tried with above approach . but it does not giving expected out put for the distinct row i added in the question. 1103 and 1102.. i updated the question

Comment: Fixed a typo  in my solution. I accidently used `F.when(F.col('source_system') == "hive"` twice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `subtract` method.
Please refer to: [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.subtract)

```
df = hive_df.subtract(snowflake_df)
```